# CDATA tags are only applied to my XML output when I call apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata, ibm-datapower

I have an XML input that I am trying to keep CDATA tags in.  I have a simple stylesheet that I am using, but for some reason that I cannot figure out, the CDATA tags only appear if I add apply-templates and put something in my template match.

Here's my XML input.  Everything in ns1:entry will have a CDATA tag.  Basically I want my output to be the exact same as my input.  I'm using DataPower for message security and it's removing the CDATA, so this XSLT is to make sure it's retained.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <User xmlns="http://google.com/schema" xmlns:ns1="http://google.com/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns1:user xmlns:ns1="http://google.com/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <ns1:userId>12345</ns1:userId>
                <ns1:extraMap ns1:size="15" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <ns1:entry ns1:key="devicetype" xsi:type="xsd:string">
                        <![CDATA[iPhone10,6]]>
                    </ns1:entry>
                    <ns1:entry ns1:key="longitude" xsi:type="xsd:string">
                        <![CDATA[-70.000000]]>
                    </ns1:entry>
                    <ns1:entry ns1:key="latitude" xsi:type="xsd:string">
                        <![CDATA[40.000000]]>
                    </ns1:entry>
                    <ns1:entry ns1:key="osname" xsi:type="xsd:string">
                        <![CDATA[iOS]]>
                    </ns1:entry>
                </ns1:extraMap>
                <ns1:profile-status>
                    <ns1:enum-class>xxxxxx</ns1:enum-class>
                    <ns1:enum-value>Active</ns1:enum-value>
                </ns1:profile-status>
            </ns1:user>
        </User>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://google.com/schema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="dp ns1 xsi">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" version="1.0"
    cdata-section-elements="ns1:entry ns1:userId" indent="yes" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

With that stylesheet, the CDATA tags are removed.  If I change the template match to the following, I get the CDATA tags, but also a message followed by a bunch of 1s (as expected).

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>1</xsl:template>
```

I can't figure out how to have the stylesheet keep the CDATA tags without having a template match that performs some function.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I've been at this for far too long and am now going in circles.

DataPower XI52 7.6.0.6

Comment: You cannot "have the stylesheet keep the CDATA tags", because the stylesheet does not see them. You must create your own CDATA sections when you create your  output.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://google.com/schema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ns1:entry" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Your own version, after removing the errors and the redundant parts, should work just as well - see: http://xsltransform.net/93wkLHY

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working.  It must be something within DataPower that is causing it, because I don't think it should be this hard.  I see it's working on the transform web page, but DataPower doesn't add the CDATA tags with that same code.  For some reason, like I said, if I add something like <xsl:template match="text()">1</xsl:template>,the CDATA tags are added, as is a "1" for every element I process.  Adding <xsl:template match="text()"/> does nothing.

Comment: I am afraid it makes no sense to me.